# amCharts line style change

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a chart which shows basic values over time: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGOaem

I want the chart's line to change after today's date (you can see I am plotting from 5 days ago until 5 days time).

Basically I want a line which becomes faded and dashed after today's date.

I am trying to achieve this through the properties:

```
alphaField, negativeLineAlpha and dashLengthField
```

No idea where I'm going wrong, have been playing with it all day :/

Comment: There's no such property that would let alternate line alpha at midpoint. You can use "dashLengthField", however it will work with regular graph only, not with the "smoothedLine" you are trying to use. As for fading the line, you can use "lineColorField" to set it it to a faded color RGB instead.

Comment: Thanks @martynasma, you were right I couldnt use smoothed line, which isnt obvious in the docs. feel free to post as answer and ill accept it